# Pixels not drawing in java applet

Tags: java, applet, awt

I wrote this program that is supposed to draw a Sierpinski triangle, however whenever I open it with appletviewer on a lower-end computer it will usually draw anywhere from 4 to 60 dots. If I re-open it without re-compiling it the number of dots will occasionally go up from the usual 4. Running it on my higher-end computer at home it works best at around 5 000 000 iterations. However, although it draws the shape fairly full, it starts to draw dots where it should not be possible for there to be dots. This only occurs when the numbers start to get higher. Why is my applet not working on lower end computers, and why does it draw pixels in the incorrect positions at greater values? Here is the code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Triangle extends Applet implements Runnable {

    Thread runner;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int xCord, yCord;
    double lastX, lastY, currentX, currentY;
    final double topX = 500, topY = 100, leftX = 200, leftY = 700,
                 rightX = 800, rightY = 700;

    public void start() {

        if (runner == null)
        {
            runner = new Thread(this);
            runner.start();
        }
    }

    public void init() {

    lastX = 500;  //Top dot
    lastY = 100;
    }   

    public void run() {

        for(int counter = 1; counter <= 5000000; counter++) {

            int n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (n == 1) { //Top dot
                currentX = topX + (lastX - topX) / 2;
                currentY = topY + (lastY - topY) / 2;
                lastX = currentX;
                lastY = currentY;
                xCord = (int)Math.round(currentX);
                yCord = (int)Math.round(currentY);
                repaint();
            } else if (n == 2) { //Left dot
                currentX = leftX + (lastX - leftX) / 2;
                currentY = leftY + (lastY - leftY) / 2;
                lastX = currentX;
                lastY = currentY;
                xCord = (int)Math.round(currentX);
                yCord = (int)Math.round(currentY);
                repaint();
            } else { //Right dot
                currentX = rightX + (lastX - rightX) / 2;
                currentY = rightY + (lastY - rightY) / 2;
                lastX = currentX;
                lastY = currentY;
                xCord = (int)Math.round(currentX);
                yCord = (int)Math.round(currentY);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {

        paint(g);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.fillRect(500, 100, 2, 2); //Top dot, dot 1
        g.fillRect(200, 700, 2, 2); //Bottom left dot, dot 2
        g.fillRect(800, 700, 2, 2); //Bottom right dot, dot 3
        g.fillRect(xCord, yCord, 2, 2); 
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code = "Triangle.class" width=999 height=799>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Applets are deprecated and no longer supported; You could be flooding the EDT with repaint requests which could causing issues. A better solution might be to use a `BufferedImage` image, paint the updates to it and then paint the image via the `paint` method

Comment: ^^ And switch to java web start if you really have that need. Or to HTML5 if you need the drawing to be inside the page

Comment: I am not familiar with the `BufferedImage` method, but if I understand correctly you must use an existing image? I don't really want to do that as I want to draw it from "scratch" and without any additional files. Would adding a delay between each paint event possibly resolve the issue? This is just a project that I did for fun

Comment: You don't understand correctly. You can create a BufferedImage "from scratch" and use it as a background image.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am fairly new to Java. Is this a minor modification to the program or will it require a full rewrite? I apologize if the question is stupid

Comment: @Tuomas I would start with a rewrite, conceptually you need to move the work you are doing and the painting it's own context and then provide a means to update the UI on each update cycle. You'll also want to get rid of the Applet and move to something which will actually work

Comment: Thanks, could you possibly recommend a resource to help me get started?